# Gridview Delete Linkbutton not firing RowDeleting Event

Tags: asp.net, gridview, rowdeleting

I am so frustrated. Using asp.net GridView. Using a LinkButton with the CommandName="Delete". Don't understand why the page isn't posting back. I've done this a million times in other apps. I've compared them against one another and nothing appears different. I will preface by saying this IS someone else's template, however, so it's not my same template.

Any ideas what might be causing my issues?

My scenario is this:

ASPX Page (edited to add the HTML; there's more HTML in the site.Master and there's also a tag for the AjaxControlToolkit at the top of the page):

```
<div class="width80 container body-content">
    <h2 class="marginTop50">Message Board</h2>
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlMsgsForUser" runat="server" Visible="false">
        <div class="jumbotronSmallFont">
            <asp:Label ID="lblErrorMessage" CssClass="has-error" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        </div>
    </asp:Panel>

    <div class="jumbotronSmallFont">
        <h4>New Message</h4>
        <form>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="messageBody">Message Body</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" id="messageBody" rows="3" style="max-width: 600px;"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="text-center">
                <button id="btnSave" class="btn btn-primary" style="width: 75px;">Save</button>
                <button type="button" id="btnReset" class="btn btn-default marginLeft15px" style="width: 75px;">Reset</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div>
        <asp:GridView ID="gvMessages" runat="server" Width="100%"
            CssClass="table adminMessageBoardTable marginAuto" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            OnRowUpdating="gvMessages_RowUpdating"
            OnRowCancelingEdit="gvMessages_RowCancelingEdit"
            OnRowDataBound="gvMessages_RowDataBound"
            OnRowEditing="gvMessages_RowEditing"
            OnRowDeleting="gvMessages_RowDeleting"
            DataKeyNames="Id" BorderStyle="NotSet">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Message" HeaderStyle-CssClass="center" SortExpression="Message">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtMsg" Width="100%" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("MessageBody") %>' ID="lblMessage"></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date Updated" SortExpression="DateUpdated" HeaderStyle-CssClass="center" ItemStyle-CssClass="center">
                    <HeaderStyle Width="120px" />
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblEditDateUpdated" Enabled="false"></asp:Label>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DateUpdated","{0:d}") %>' ID="lblDateUpdated"></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Updated By" SortExpression="UpdatedBy" HeaderStyle-CssClass="center" ItemStyle-CssClass="center">
                    <HeaderStyle Width="120px" />
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" Text="" ID="lblEditUpdatedBy" Enabled="false"></asp:Label>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("UpdatedBy") %>' ID="lblUpdatedBy"></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-CssClass="center">
                    <HeaderStyle Width="120px" />
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lbUpdate" runat="server" CausesValidation="True"
                            CommandName="Update" Text="Update"
                            OnClientClick="return confirm('You are about to update this entry.  \n\nDo you wish to proceed?');"></asp:LinkButton>
                        &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="lbCancel" runat="server" CausesValidation="False"
                            CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel"></asp:LinkButton>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lbEdit" runat="server" CausesValidation="False"
                            CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit"></asp:LinkButton> &nbsp; &nbsp;
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lbDelete" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id") %>' CausesValidation="False" 
                            CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" OnClientClick="return confirm('You are about to delete this entry. \n\Do you wish to proceed?');"></asp:LinkButton>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>

    </div>

</div>
```

In my code-behind, I have:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            var user = CommonFunctions.GetUserID(true);
            var Admin = Roles.IsUserInRole(user, "Administrator");
            var Dev = Roles.IsUserInRole(user, "Developer");

            if (!Admin && !Dev)
            {
                Response.Redirect("~/");
            }

            gvBind(true);
        }
    }
```

When I click on the Delete linkbutton for a row, it drops into the Page_Load and

```
!Page.IsPostBack
```

verifies as **true**. I have no idea why it's doing this. It also never even hits the RowDeleting command. My breakpoint is so sad.

In my other app, all the markup and code-behind are pretty much the same. The only differences are the gridview name and the Eval tags. But when I click Delete in that app, it skips the !Page.IsPostBack section. :( It also obviously fires the RowDeleting.

I've also tried implementing RowCommand, but that event never fires either. It only does Page_Load and RowDataBound before essentially refreshing the page.

Any ideas?

Please, and thanks!!!

Comment: When you hit delete, is the server-side `Page_Load()` executing only once, or more than once? If more than once, is `IsPostBack` ever = `true`?

Comment: It only hits once, @anu start. It doesn't appear to be true. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working fine. When I click Delete button, it triggers `gvMessages_RowDeleting` event. Here is how I test it -

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvMessages" runat="server" Width="100%"
    CssClass="GridView marginAuto" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    OnRowDeleting="gvMessages_RowDeleting"
    DataKeyNames="Id">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Message" HeaderStyle-CssClass="center" SortExpression="Message">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("MessageBody") %>' ID="lblMessage"></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-CssClass="center">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lbDelete" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id") %>' CausesValidation="False"
                    CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete"
                    OnClientClick="confirm('You are about to delete this entry. \n\Do you wish to proceed?');"></asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

### Code Behind

```
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string MessageBody { get; set; }
}

public partial class _Default : Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            gvMessages.DataSource = new List<Item>
            {
                new Item {Id = 1, MessageBody = "One"},
                new Item {Id = 2, MessageBody = "Two"},
                new Item {Id = 3, MessageBody = "Three"},
            };
            gvMessages.DataBind();
        }
    }

    protected void gvMessages_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, the code should be fine. It is literally a copycat of my other project. There must be something else causing it to act strangely, though, bc it still steps through the if(!IsPostBack) statement. It never fires RowDeleting. Maybe I need to re-draw the entire page. I have no idea.

Comment: This is so dumb. I just re-drew the page and re-created everything, and now it's working. -_- Thank you for your help! I have no idea why Visual Studio is being a punk.

Answer (score 0):

```
 OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure?');"
```

Try to add the return from your confirm statement.

Comment: Same thing @L0uis. Sorry, I had the return earlier but must have deleted it when I was attempting all the different things I'd read about lol. But yeah, putting it back in didn't change anything. :/